# store procedure de 2 tablas con un print

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Me podrían orientar para crear un *stored procedure* con un `print`;
por ejemplo: (tienda de tenis) se tiene en existencia 15 pares de un producto, al comprar 16 muestre un `print` de que no hay suficientes.

En la tabla `producto` tengo estas columnas: `(idproducto, tipo, nombre, descripcion, talla, vendido, procedencia, existencia)`.

En la tabla `venta` tengo estas columnas: `(idventa, producto, cant, fecha, hora, cliente, empleado, lanzamiento, popular)`.

Tengo estos 2 *SP*:

```
create proc sp_restarexistencia
@idproducto
as varchar (5),
@cant 
as INT 
as
UPDATE producto set Existencia = Existencia - @cant where idproducto = @idproducto  
 


EXEC sp_restarexistencia 'pro01', 1 

create proc sp_Sumarexistencia
@idproducto
as varchar (5),
@cant 
as INT 
as
UPDATE producto set Existencia = Existencia + @cant where idproducto = @idproducto

exec sp_Sumarexistencia 'pro01', 13
```

Cualquier aporte es bueno. Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenidx! Disculpa pero no entiendo del todo qué buscas hacer. Qué debe mostrarse en el print? Debe salir en la consola del cliente que estés usando para ejecutar el SP?

Comment: Hola . Gracias . Lo que busco hacer es que al querer adquirir mayor cantidad de la que hay en existencia muestre un print " No hay cantidad suficiente" . Si exacto , no se si logre explicarme ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolverlo de manera, simple, puedes utilizar una condicional `if` para comprobar que la existencia actual en la tabla sea mayor a la cantidad a restar.

```
create proc sp_restarexistencia
    @idproducto varchar (5)
  , @cant INT 
as
begin
  if (select Existencia from producto where idproducto = @idproducto) >= @cant
    UPDATE producto set Existencia = Existencia - @cant where idproducto = @idproducto 
  else
    print `existencia insuficiente` 
end
go
```

En el `if`, lanzo una consulta que me devolverá la existencia actual y comparo ese resultado con la cantidad que voy a restar. Si es mayor o igual, hago la resta de la existencia y si no, imprimo el mensaje `existencia insuficiente`.

**Advertencia**: En sistemas con concurrencia esto tiene la posibilidad de fallar, pues dos transacciones pueden estar ejecutando el SP a la vez, de manera que cuando ambas consultas se ejecutan como parte del `if`, la existencia sea suficiente para cubrir la cantidad de cada una, pero la suma de ambas cantidades supere la existencia del producto. Si bien una de las dos transacciones realizará el `update` primero y la otra se verá obligada a esperar a que esa transacción termine, con una aplicación bien diseñada, donde las transacciones tardan solo milesimas de segundo, logrará realizar su propio `update` después de la espera (sin dar *timeout*), dejando la existencia con un valor negativo.

Sin embargo, parece conveniente como respuesta simple para un que el AP, que apenas comienza con bases de datos, pueda comprender como realizar este tipo de operaciones.